# AD domain controller user replication with group membership

Tags: powershell, authentication, active-directory, group, domaincontroller

Trying to figure out why a PowerShell domain controller replication job for a user object does not sync groupmemberships (memberOf).

```
$users = 'wtst, tst'
$usersArray = $users.Split(',')

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {`
        $using:usersArray | ForEach-Object {`
        (Write-Output "Processing user $($_)..."), `
        ((Sync-ADObject -Object "CN=$_,OU=XXXX,DC=XXXX,DC=XXXX" -Source 'XXXX' -Destination 'XXXX'))
    }
} -ComputerName 'XXXX' -Credential $(Get-Credential)
```

Other profile properties sync just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What status code is being returned?  200 OK or a 400/500 error?

Comment: PowerShell terminal does not return codes as far as I know.

Comment: Check Event Viewer on local and remote machines and see if there is an error.

Comment: You could try with `repadmin /syncall` tho hopefully this is a test domain. Replication is not something you should be forcing in a production environment. I'm not certain that `Sync-ADObject` forces replication of the object's attributes, only forces the replication of the object itself. In any case, ignore the comments from the above user, they're either trolling or have no idea what they talk about or both.

Comment: Your infrastructure would have to be really bad if it could not handle a manual sync of AD lol. There is no harm to repadmin /syncall

Comment: As per MSFT: To sync user object group memberships with Sync-ADObject, you need to specify the -Object parameter with the distinguished name of the user object. For example:

Sync-ADObject -Object "CN=John Smith,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com" -Source "DC1" -Destination "DC2"

This will replicate the user object and its group memberships from DC1 to DC2.

Other Attributes are synched just fine. That's why I thought my script was wrong.

Comment: repadmin /syncall replicates the entire AD-structure as far as I'm aware. Little hesitant about that.

Comment: Found repadmin /replsingleobj but even that doesn't sync group memberships.

Comment: Well, not even repadmin /syncall /APed synched memberOf. No errors..